# Lua how to assign default array value to '0' not nil

Tags: lua, love2d

I was getting lately an error in Lua saying cannot assign arithmetic value of '?'. then I realized that I need to define how many storage are in my array and assigning them to a value,

this gave me Error : `locator = {}`

this Worked fine : `locator = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}`

So now I have another array that I need a loop to store 200 values in it, so how to define the storage and values within it without something like this : a = {0,0,0,0,0,...... etc}

Any Ideas ?

Comment: `locator = {}; for i = 1, 200 do locator[i] = 0 end`

Comment: Sometimes this may work: `locator = setmetatable({}, {__index = function() return 0 end})`

Answer (score 3):

this is what worked for me :

```
locator = {}

for i = 1, 200 do 
locator[i] = 0 
end
```

just assigning all to 0 inside a loop Before using them

*Credits : Egor Skriptunoff*